# Using the Youtube Iframe API

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to get going with the Youtube player API in order to toggle a video when I close a modal box.

Here's my code, it's creating the iframe as said, but the button has no API control over said iframe.

```
<div id="player"></div>    

<script type="text/javascript">
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '500',
        width: '800',
        videoId: 'f37MOGHMrlI'
      });
}

$(".toggle1").click(function(){
  alert("Pausing " + player);//is undefined :(
  player.pauseVideo();
});

</script>
```

Anybody knows what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

While it would be necessary to see the entire structure of your page to know for sure, because your script is in the `body` my guess would be that the button with class `toggle1` has not been added to the DOM at the time that your `click` handler is assigned.  Either wrap that handler assignment in `$(document).ready`, or:

```
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '500',
        width: '800',
        videoId: 'f37MOGHMrlI'
        events: {
          onReady: configureButton
        }
      });
}

function configureButton() {
  $(".toggle1").click(function(){
    player.pauseVideo();
  });
}
```